# Search for specific Layer in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have a drawing with about 500 Layers structured with sublayers.
Is there a way to search for a specific Layer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while in the layers panel? I believe that will open a search box and search by layer name.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: THere you can only search for objects in general. I did not see an option to search for a layername.

Comment: @user1344545 Just check out the screenshot from my updated answer, just click on any layer, press Ctrl+F and type the name of the layer you want. It will take you to it and highlight it.

Comment: Oh. Maybe I have an older version. I will check. Thank you so much.

Comment: Searching works with new version. Thanks. Is there a way to search Sublayers which parents are collabsed (closed) I have always to open all layers to search in sublayers. THis is timeconsuming.